# Compiling against 64bits DLL cause segfault but works in 32bits

Tags: c, dll, 32bit-64bit, mingw-w64

**Context**

On Windows, using mingw32 and its x86_64 version. In order to use a third-party library (within Unity), I'am trying to build a wrapper library (dll) around the native one (to simplify the integration in Unity). I need this library to be 64bits.

The problem arises when linking against the created wrapper library in a test program: the program crash on a segfault, whereas the 32bits version runs just fine.

**Procedure**

I am using the 32 and 64bits version of the dll provided by the third-party (see Dependencies analysis on Picture) to compile wrapping libraries.

[image: Native dlls into Dependencies]

The wrapper library is simply wrapping some functions of the native library. The header is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ATC3DG.h"

#pragma once
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) int trakSTAR_Init();
    __declspec(dllexport) int trakSTAR_GetMeasurement(double S1_X[3], double S1_A[3], double *S1_T, unsigned short * S1_Q, double S2_X[3], double S2_A[3], double *S2_T, unsigned short * S2_Q, double S3_X[3], double S3_A[3], double *S3_T, unsigned short * S3_Q);
    __declspec(dllexport) int trakSTAR_Close();
    __declspec(dllexport) void trakSTAR_ErrorName(int errorcode, char *errortxt);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

It is compiling fine for both the 32 and 64bits versions respectively with:

`mingw32-gcc.exe -shared -Iinclude -o bin\Release\libWrapper.dll WrapperLib.c lib\win32\nativelib.lib`

and

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -shared -Iinclude -o bin\Release\libWrapper64.dll WrapperLib.c lib\win64\nativelib64.lib`

Then, compiling test codes linking this Wrapper dll using respectively:

`mingw32-gcc.exe -I.\include -L.\test -llibWrapper .\test\MainTest.c -o test\Test32`

and

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -g -I.\include -L.\test .\test\MainTest.c -o test\Test64 -llibWrapper64`

also works fine and produce the two executables.

**Problem**

Now, while the 32bits version (`Test32.exe`) runs fine, the 64bits version produce a Segfault straight ahead (no even first console print). The necessary dll (native and wrapper for both 32 and 64bits version are in the execution folder).

When inspecting the two Wrapper dlls with Dependencies, I can't see any major difference (see picture).

[image: The two wrapper dlls into Dependencies]

**What could be the cause of the problem with the 64bits library?**

**What are my options to understand what is going wrong and debug/inspect further?**

Note: Compiling a test code against the native dll works fine for both in 32 and 64 bits.

Note2: Running GDB on the faulty test program does not provide more information.

Comment: Too few details. What was *nativelib* created with? Is it static? As its ext suggests, use it with *VStudio*.  Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati. I have tried to add more details. Note that I am not sure on the _nativelib_ as provided by a third-party, but yes it seems to have been build with VStudio (given provided examples with their API and the demangler in the 32bits version). The thing is that the issue arises when I am using my own wrapping library and not when using directly the 64bits _nativelib_.